# Single responsibility principle confusion

Tags: c#, solid-principles

i am going through [**this**](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/137636/taking-the-single-responsibility-principle-seriously/) article to understand SRP.
There is a IModem interface initially

```
interface IModem : IDisposable
{
    void Dial(String number);
    void Send(char c);
    char Recv();
}
```

This interface has two responsibilities One is Connection and other is Data Exchange so it should be broken down in sub-interface and what is done :-

```
interface IModemConnection : IDisposable
{
    void Dial(String number);
} 

interface IModemDataExchange
{
    void Send(char c);
    char Recv();
}
```

Till this part i got understand but further the above interface are changed like below and i am not able to get what public **IModemDataExchange Dial(String number);** Part is doing.

```
interface IModemConnection : IDisposable
{
    IModemDataExchange Dial(String number);
}

interface IModemDataExchange
{
    void Send(char c);
    char Recv();
}
```

can anybody tell me why we have done that.

Comment: You can only exchange data with the modem once connected, can't you?

Comment: @CédricBignon i am reading about SOlID principles and i am not implimenting anything. What i want to know what "public IModemDataExchange Dial(String number);" this part is doing that's it.

Comment: It only allows the developer to use Send and Recv methods if Dial has been called.

Comment: @loop because the code won't compile.  Interface members must be public so it is illegal to use an access modifier on an interface member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tutorial has a sentence like

> The modem connection implementation becomes a factory for a data
>   exchange implementation

. As far as I understand, author aimed to return a dataexchange object whenever you dial another modem (when a connection is established). Of course there are other issues about signalling part, for ex. accepting the call/request and etc. However, author did not go into this detail, because this may be a little bit out off topic for this tutorial. In my opinion Dial returns an IModemDataExchange that you can call Send/Recv on that object. For example,

```
using (IModemConnection modemConnection = new IsdnModem())
{
    IModemDataExchange dataExchange = modemConnection.Dial("123456")
    dataExchange.Send("Hello");
}
```

As the author implies, Dial calls another modem and creates a data path in order to communicate through this data path. Its about factory pattern also.

Comment: <PickyMode>You should not use `if` in your example, but `using` as the `IModemDataExchange` implements the `IDisposable` interface. Also, after the `if`, your `dataexchange` might be null. </PickyMode>

Comment: I just gave a simple example, not consider Dispose(). I will edit it.

Comment: I believe others will read your excellent answer and might even copy your example. That is why I was a bit picky.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go through the whole article, but the example is simple: when you have just `public void Dial(String number);` in `IModemConnection` the objects that are used via this interface can just dial and... well, if they just dial, because of `void` return "type" there is nothing else to do after calling this method. A bit useless, right?
 So in order to do something after calling the `Dial` method the interface now returns `IModemDataExchange` object that can be used to `Send` and `Receive`.
It could be pretty ok to return `void` if the `IModem` interface wasn't split in 2 separate interfaces (you can see [.NET SqlConnection Open method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as example of the same method concept that returns `void`). But to force and show the SRP principle the author decided to give this example and by this design `Dial(String number)` should return the `IModemDataExchange` result that can be used to do other operations after dial.

Answer (score 0):

Remember:

- Single responsibility: each interface looks after a single responsibility
- Open for extension closed for modification:
- Liskov Substitution: Interfaces are passed round so you can substitute different classes that all use the interface
- Interface segregation: because of the separation one change wont affect another!
- Dependency inversion: By using interfaces and implementing your SOLID rules you are ready for Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection!

So when you create an instance of IModemConnection and call Dial(123456) it passes back an instance of an interface IModemDataExchange. This basically says once you have connected you are then interested in exchanging data from any class that use the interface IModemDataExchange. Anything else on the class is in addition!

Comment: It's Dependency Inversion which is not the same thing as Dependency Injection. And it's Interface Segregation and not Isolation. Know your principles.